# Swift: How do I include or use darwin compactdecimalformat?

Tags: swift, unicode, number-formatting, darwin

I've been investigating and trying to code a compact number format otherwise known as a short scale formatter or a humanizing big numbers into smaller ones in Swift.

I suddenly thought rather than trying to recode the wheel maybe `Unicode` already solved this issue and saw that there is indeed some code to compact larger numbers.

In the open-source code for Apple Swift on Github there is a reference to `compactdecimalformat.h` at:

https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/bootstrap/x86_64-apple-darwin/usr/local/include/unicode/compactdecimalformat.h

In it, it refers to numberformatter.h; which I found a reference from Unicode ICU 67.1 at:

https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/numberformatter_8h.html

However, I am not sure how to use it.  I've imported Darwin, but I am not sure how to actually call `compactdecimalformat` or the public identifier `DecimalFormat`

I'd like to run some number tests against it to see if it is what I'm looking for in terms of compacting / short scaling numbers.

Thus my question is, how do you include and use the compactdecimalnumber.h file that comes as part of the Darwin import?

With thanks

edit:  I think upon reading the code and comments the .h file only handles really big numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such formatter in Swift but you can subclass NumberFormatter and create your own CompactNumberFormatter if needed:

```
class CompactDecimalFormatter: NumberFormatter {
    override func string(for obj: Any?) -> String? {
        guard var value = (obj as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue else { return nil }
        let suffixes = ["", "k", "m", "b","t"]
        var index = suffixes.startIndex
        while index < suffixes.endIndex && value.magnitude >= 1000 {
            index = suffixes.index(after: index)
            value /= 1000
        }
        formatter.positiveSuffix = suffixes[index]
        formatter.negativeSuffix = suffixes[index]
        return formatter.string(for: value)
    }

    private let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.roundingMode = .down
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
        return formatter
    }()

    // You can override all the properties you thing you might need
    override var minimumIntegerDigits: Int {
        get { formatter.minimumIntegerDigits }
        set { formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = newValue }
    }
    override var maximumIntegerDigits: Int {
        get { formatter.maximumIntegerDigits }
        set { formatter.maximumIntegerDigits = newValue }
    }

    override var minimumFractionDigits: Int {
        get { formatter.minimumFractionDigits }
        set { formatter.minimumFractionDigits = newValue }
    }
    override var maximumFractionDigits: Int {
        get { formatter.maximumFractionDigits }
        set { formatter.maximumFractionDigits = newValue }
    }

    override var positivePrefix: String! {
        get { formatter.positivePrefix }
        set { formatter.positivePrefix = newValue }
    }
    override var negativePrefix: String! {
        get { formatter.negativePrefix }
        set { formatter.negativePrefix = newValue }
    }

    override var roundingMode: RoundingMode {
        get{ formatter.roundingMode }
        set{ formatter.roundingMode = newValue }
    }

    // or disable them
    override var numberStyle: Style { get { .decimal } set { } }
    override var positiveSuffix: String! { get { "" } set { } }
    override var negativeSuffix: String! { get { "" } set { } }
}
```

---

```
let formatter = CompactDecimalFormatter()
formatter.string(for: 2500)  // "2.5k"
```

Comment: Thats a shame, I thought I could leverage the work undertaken and codified by the Unicode stuff.    But I'll give it a go

Comment: I've tried it out for some numbers, and it seems to work on this range:  `let numbers = [
121357,17835,999999,13758314,125885,65000,5000,55995
]

numbers.forEach { (number) in
    let number = NSNumber(value: number)
    print (formatter.string(from: number) as Any)
}`

Comment: There are 2 main problems with this code.   (1) Reliance upon the suffixes being in the right order and referring to the correct value representation.  (2) There is no checking to see if its in the boundary as set by the suffix. (3) Localisation - but this is outside of scope, so no worries.    I'll try to add some functionality to extend your work to set boundary checking / suffix checking.

Comment: I've been reading the Unicode document at https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-numbers.html#Compact_Number_Formats   it appears they do a pattern match against a number range and return a format like `## K` with localisation variants.   I'll stick at it for now.

Comment: No need to convert your value to NSNumber. You can use Formatter’s string(for: Any) method and pass an Integer or a Double

Comment: Ok, understood.   I think for now your answer is good enough to get a basic one working.  I was experimenting ideas with a dictionary, like `10e6 : "M"` and a bundle with localised strings for the key/value pairing between 10e6 and M.   But I think your answer is good enough to get it working for now

Comment: I've looked at how Twitter does it. From its github, I found that it has a yaml file which sets up patterns (as per Unicode); https://github.com/twitter/twitter-cldr-js/blob/master/lib/assets/javascripts/twitter_cldr/es-US.js  I think what they do is "normalize" the number inputted and do a pattern match; but not sure exactly how.

Comment: Looks like there is a pull request to hopefully address this: https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/pull/2710

Comment: I'm just going to accept your answer; its not specifically answered about using the compactnumber.h file; but I think the real answer for now is you have to roll your own or use hacks to get around it.   If I ever get a better/more useful answer I'll update it; but for now, accepted.